# Ratio test in my book

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My book writes

If $|x_{n+1}/x_n| \geq 1$ for all sufficiently large $n$, then $\sum{x_n}$ diverges.

However, I thought the ratio test was inconclusive at $1$? Is this ratio test different from the standard ratio test?

Comment: The "standard" ratio test is a "convergence" test.

Comment: Typo? What is the $r$ in your statement?

Comment: @LouisPan Yes, a typo, removed

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: This is not a limit test. You don't calculate the limit of the ratio $|x_{n+1}/x_n|$, you study its behavior and compare it to $1$.

Comment: @Shaun Strichartz, Analysis

Comment: @BernardMasse Ohh, I see, thank you!

Comment: The exact situation that your question is focusing on is covered in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Comment: Do you mean, *"The Way of Analysis"*?

Comment: This is equivalent to $|x_{n+1}|\geq |x_n|>0$ for sufficiently large $n,$ so it is not possible for $x_n\to0.$

Comment: @BernardMasse how can I relate this version of ratio test, to the limit version of ratio test?